# Apple in App__purchase

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

Hi I am an iOS developer we are developing a app for readers where my app will display or load content from a cloud.
Can we avoid I app purchase and sell subscription from our website.

Comment: You can allow the user to login and access content that they have purchased on the website but there cannot be a link or mention of the web site in your app.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about Apple policy, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowing users to purchase from website, you should not mention anything related to purchase within app. As this will lead to rejection. Although, you can show the purchased content on the app. That's okay.